# IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line does not conform to RFC 7230 when POST-accessing Spring Controller

Tags: spring

I want to implement a user registration functionality with Spring. When I try to POST the data to the spring controller, the exception above is thrown. Surprisingly, GET Requests work on the controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(RestApi.ANONYMOUS + "register")
public class RegisterController {

@PostMapping(value="/new", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public UserRegistrationResultDto registerUser(@RequestBody UserRegisterDto dto) {
    UserRegistrationResultDto result = registerService.registerUser(dto.getMail(), 
                                       dto.getPassword(), dto.getRepeatedPassword());
    return result;
 }

@GetMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    return "get success";
 }
}
```

The request that fails with error code 400 is the following:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/anonymous/register/new
     Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
{
mail=data&password=data&passwordRepeated=data
}
```

It throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line [{: ] does not conform to RFC 7230 and has been ignored.
```

This get request however works:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/anonymous/register/test
```

I am using Tomcat 9 as a server.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how the `POST` request is submitted...but a space after `:` is required for HTTP header fields:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```